# Simplify a simply fraction

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify a fraction which is (x^2+y^2)/r^2. And the assumption is r^2==x^2+y^2. In this problem, x,y and r are reals and r is not 0. I have tried this:

```
FullSimplify[(x^2 + y^2)/r^2, r^2 == x^2 + y^2]
```

But it not works. The result is (x^2+y^2)/r^2. Actually it should be 1.

Comment: `FullSimplify[x^2 + y^2, r^2 == x^2 + y^2]` does not work, either. Neither does, `FullSimplify[(r2)/r^2, r2 == r^2]`.

Comment: `FullSimplify[(x^2 + y^2) r^2, (x^2 + y^2) r^2 == 1]` works but not `FullSimplify[(x^2 + y^2)/r^2, (x^2 + y^2)/r^2 == 1]`. Guess it has to do with division. But divide by zero is the only problem I can think of, and `x/x` becomes `1` automatically. And `FullSimplify[(x^2 + y^2)/r^2, (x^2 + y^2)/r^2 == 0]` becomes `0`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Do you think this is a bug then? I think it should have worked as is without any workaround.

Comment: @Nasser I think this issue of identities not being applied in Simplify (in the obvious-to-human way) has come up before. I failed to find a pertinent Q&A so far. But I think any reasonable person would think this should work. So probably worth reporting to WRI.

Comment: This works: `FullSimplify[r^2/(x^2 + y^2), x^2 + y^2 == r^2]`. This does not do what I anticipated: `FullSimplify[(x^2 + y^2) r^4, x^2 + y^2 == r^2]`. Hard to see a pattern...

Comment: `Simplify[(x^2 + y^2)/r^2 /. {x -> r Cos[\[Theta]], 
   y -> r Sin[\[Theta]]}]`

Comment: `Simplify[(x^2 + y^2)/r^2] /. r^-2 -> 1/(x^2 + y^2)`

Comment: To me the proper algebraic move is `Last@PolynomialReduce[(x^2 + y^2)/r^2, {x^2 + y^2 - r^2}, {x, y, r}]`, if we just want to get the right answer.

Comment: fyi, I tried the same thing in Maple (it also has side-relation for simplify) and it just worked as is. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V40g.png)  So I think Mathematica should have been able to also do it.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha has no problem with (x^2+y^2)/r^2 and  r^2==x^2+y^2

Comment: I think you should report this to: support@wolfrm.com

Comment: @Lou interesting. When writing in Alpha `Simplify[(x^2+y^2)/r^2,r^2==x^2+y^2]` it does not work. But `(x^2+y^2)/r^2 and r^2==x^2+y^2` works and it gives `1`. I bet they are using AI for this and not the normal Mathematica Kernel.

Comment: Actually from my try, I find that if I use a,b,c then there is no problem. But as for the 'r', there is the problem above.

Comment: @SuperLoop You are right. This deepens the mystery.  Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5lx8.png)  with your permission, can I add this screen shot to my answer?

Comment: @Nasser Certainly, though I do not get what your means. But I think the problem is a bug in Mathematica.

Comment: Also, either `(x^2 + y^2)/r^2 /. Solve[r^2 == x^2 + y^2, r][[1]]` or `(x^2 + y^2)/r^2 /. Solve[r^2 == x^2 + y^2, r][[-1]]`

Comment: `Simplify[(x^2 + y^2)/r^2, {r^2 == x^2 + y^2, r==#}]&/@{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,s,t,u,v,w,z}` also produces a strange result (with only 'z' producing the 'right' answer of 1, and contrast behaviour of (a - q) with (s-w))

Answer (score 7):

Until someone finds better solution, you can always use this workaround

```
  ClearAll[x,y,r,A]
  Simplify[(x^2 + y^2)/r^2, {x^2 + y^2 == A}] /. A -> r^2

  (* 1 *)
```

Mathematica side relation substitution does not seem to like compound expression on the RHS. (This is only reason I see why it did not work). This for example will not work:

```
  Simplify[(x^2 + y^2)/r^2, {x^2 + y^2 == r^2}]
```

Since `r^2` is not a single symbol. So to use the side-relation, need to use single symbol on the RHS, then replace this back with whatever you needed.

**Update**
Thanks to observation by @SuperLoop in the comment above, this behavior is also affected by what symbols are used. When using other symbols, now Simplify does what is expected.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There were similar issues before where lexicographic ordering or what symbols used made difference in result.

Version 13.01 on windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Reduce`and Nasser's suggestion:

```
Part[#, 2]&@First@Sort[Reduce[{(x^2 + y^2)/r^2 == A, x^2 + y^2 == r^2}]]
(*1*)
```